# is there a reson why my android app attaches a json object to a HTTP request only in debug but not in release version?

Tags: android, fast-android-networking

My Android app recently stopped attaching a JSON object to the post request only in the release version. In debug, it works flawlessly.
I have checked the usage.txt file and the addJsonBody method is not there.
I have tried minifying the debug version, but it still works well in debug.
I'm using Fast Android Networking https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Edit: Some extra context. This is my code:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("uid", user.getUid());
jsonObject.put("email", user.getEmail());
Logging.logObject(jsonObject);
AndroidNetworking.post(Globals.HOST + "/api/user/uid")
.addJSONObjectBody(jsonObject)
.build();
```

I can see the jsonobject in logcat but I also see this (Release version):

--> POST https://example.com/api/user/uid http/1.1 (0-byte body)

<-- 400  https://example.com/api/user/uid (1169ms, unknown-length body)